# Difference between CSS + selector and ~ selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I saw a `.class1 ~ .class2` selector today, and had to look it up.

```
div ~ p {}
```

Selects every `<p>` element that are preceded by a `<div>` element.  In other words,

```
<div></div>
<p></p>
```

The `<p></p>` would be selected, right?

And then there's the `+` selector:

```
div + p {}
```

Selects all `<p>` elements that are placed immediately after `<div>` elements.  In other words,

```
<div></div>
<p></p>
```

Am I right to think these are equivalent, or am I missing something?

Comment: w3c and w3schools are not the same, please don't ever confuse the 2.

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

Comment: I'm surprised this isn't a dupe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your specific scenario, these two selectors are equivalent, however not in more general scenarios.

There is one important difference, the `+` combinator states:

> The elements represented by the two sequences share the same parent in
>   the document tree and the element represented by the first sequence
>   **immediately** precedes the element represented by the second one.

Imagine this scenario:

```
<div></div>
<p></p>      <!-- this will be selected with the + combinator -->

<p></p>      <!-- these two paragraphs will be affected by the ~ combinator -->
<p></p>      <!-- but NOT by the + combinator -->
```

And please don't confuse the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/), a serious institution standardizing web technologies, with w3schools which is a rather [bad source for information](http://www.w3fools.com/)!

Comment: Duly noted that w3schools was not made by the W3C.

Answer (score 3):

From spec: [Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#sibling-combinators)

> **8.3.1. Adjacent sibling combinator (`+`)**
>
> The elements represented by the two sequences share the same parent in the document tree and the element represented by the first sequence **immediately** precedes the element represented by the second one.

> **8.3.2. General sibling combinator (`~`)**
>
> The elements represented by the two sequences share the same parent in the document tree and the element represented by the first sequence precedes **(not necessarily immediately)** the element represented by the second one.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is the `+` will select the very next(adjacent) single element whereas `~` will select all preceded elements on the same level. But anyways you have the definition so I would like to contribute some simple real world scenario for better understanding.

```
div + p {
    color: red;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/guuR2/) *Using `+`*

---

```
div ~ p {
    color: red;
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/guuR2/1/) *Using `~`*

So here, in the first example, it selects the `p` element which is adjacent to `div` but won't select the `p` which is later adjacent to the first `p` whereas if you use `~`,
 it will select all the `p` elements which are followed by `div` element.