# What does this symbol mean in CSS?

Tags: css

### What is this?

This is a collection of questions that come up every now and then about syntax in CSS. This is also a Community Wiki, **so everyone is invited to participate in maintaining this list.**

### Why is this?

Stack Overflow does not allow searching for particular characters. As a consequence, many questions about operators and other syntax tokens are not found easily when searching for them. This also makes closing duplicates more difficult. The list below is to help with this issue.

The main idea is to have links to existing questions on Stack Overflow, so it's easier for us to reference them, not to copy over content from the various CSS Specifications.

Additionally, this is a blatant copy of the [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/1529630) symbol reference. We needed a CSS one.

---

**Please help. Edit and add links to other operators/syntax references, or if you can't find good questions/answers on a particular piece of syntax, add an answer to this question and link it**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Universal selector `*`

- `*`: [What does "*" mean in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8715860/1529630)

---

Combinators

- Child `>`: [What does the ">" (greater-than sign) CSS selector mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3225891/1529630)
- Following-sibling `~`: [What does the "~" (tilde/squiggle/twiddle) CSS selector mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10782054/1529630)
- Next-sibling `+`: [What does the "+" (plus sign) CSS selector mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1139763/1529630)
- `~` vs `+`: [Difference between CSS + selector and ~ selector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21264820/1529630)

---

Pseudo-classes

- `:focus`, `:active`: [What is the difference between :focus and :active?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1677990/1529630)
- `:root`: [What's the difference between CSS3's :root pseudo class and html?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15899615/1529630)

---

Attribute selectors

- `[att|=val]`, `[att^=val]`: [What is the difference between pipe (|) and caret (^) attribute selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34530852/1529630)

---

Namespaces

- Namespace separator `|`: [What does *|* this mean in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3608819/1529630)
- `@namespace` rule: [What is the use of @namespace in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24878905/1529630)

---

Nesting

- Nesting selector `&`: [use of &:before in css and difference with ::before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77072781/19068)

---

Shadow DOM

- `/deep/` combinator, `::shadow` pseudo-element: [What do /deep/ and ::shadow mean in a CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25609678/1529630)

---

Important declarations

- `!important`: [What are the implications of using "!important" in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3706819/1529630)

---

Hacks

- `*`: [What does a star-preceded property mean in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1667531/1529630)
- `:)`: [What does the smiley face ":)" mean in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25444328/1529630)