# css: what does '>' sign mean between two elements ?

Tags: css

For example, in this code:

```
tr:last-child>td:first-child {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 25px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 25px;  
}
```

'tr:last-child' means the last element of type tr. 'td:first-child' means the last element of type td. What does the '>' sign between them mean?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: [What does this symbol mean in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39710045/1529630)

Answer (score 0):

> The > combinator separates two selectors and matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are direct children of elements matched by the first. By contrast, when two selectors are combined with the descendant selector, the combined selector expression matches those elements matched by the second selector for which there exists an ancestor element matched by the first selector, regardless of the number of "hops" up the DOM

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors

in your case :

```
tr:last-child>td:first-child {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 25px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 25px;  
}
```

it says direct child of tr

Answer (score 0):

it means second selector should be direct child of first selector

example

```
<div>
  <p>hi</p>
</div>
```

and

```
<div>
  <section>
    <p> hi </p>
  </section>
</div>
```

if you do

```
div>p {
  color : red;
}
```

first case will have color red as **p** is direct child(>) of **div**

while in second case its called descendant in general and is not a direct child

read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors

Answer (score 0):

It this case it's pointing to the element inside the tr:last-child which is td:first-last. For which you are writing CSS properties...!