# Use of &:before in CSS and difference with ::before

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the following code, I don't understand `&:before`.

```css
                    .coloring {
                      &:before {
                        background: "black";
                      }
                    }
```

Is it a built-in class or is a class maybe created by a collaborator?

Is **&** required? (I looked on the web and found that some uses **::before**)

Comment: This is SASS syntax.

Comment: I had no idea about it, is `&:before` is SASS and `::before` CSS ? @DallogFheir

Comment: `&` is parent selector in SASS, in this case it's equivalent to `.coloring::before` in pure CSS.

Comment: The `&` nesting selector is part of the CSS Nesting Module, and it already has partial support in some browsers - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Nesting_selector

Comment: [Sass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_(style_sheet_language))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` is the [CSS nesting selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Nesting_selector). It's very new and doesn't have full support in all major browsers yet (although it is getting close).

The use of a single `:` is a hang-over from the time before CSS was changed to distinguish pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements with different syntax.

```css
.coloring {
    &::before {
        background: "black";
    }
}
```

is equivalent to:

```css
.coloring::before {
    background: "black";
}
```

It's not a very practical use here, but consider an example where there were rules applied to both the element itself and the pseudo-element. Then it avoids having to repeat the first part of the selector for two different rule-sets.

```css
.coloring {
    color: red;

    &::before {
        background: "black";
    }
}
```

The same syntax is used in [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax/).

Comment: if I return`coloring` using computed property as following `coloring() {   return { background: "black" };   },` how to bind **before** to it ?

Comment: @nayakhattar — how you change the CSS applied to a ::before pseudo-element using JavaScript has nothing to do with the question this is an answer to. You could ask a new question about it but there are probably duplicates out there already.

Comment: actually I can't ask further questions for now